# Android MultiAutoCompleteTextView : Except values other than Adapter

Tags: android, multiautocompletetextview

I am stuck with one problem that i have one `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` as shown in below image:

In that i am selecting **city name** from suggestion of `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` and adding that item in `ListView` (as below). **I want to prevent to enter other entries rather than `ADAPTER` values.**

[image]

I am binding code this way and `onClick` of `Button` I am separating values by comma:

```
private void initComp() { //              GET DATA FROM DATABASE

    multiSelectCities = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_multiselect_city);
    btnGetCity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_btn_slect_city);
    listCity = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_get_city_list);
    btnGetCity.setOnClickListener(this);
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    dbHelper.open();
    setName();
    // dbHelper.close();
}

public void setName() { // FOR SET THE NAME IN MULTISELECT TEXTVIEW
    final Cursor localcursor = dbHelper.getArea();

    if ((localcursor != null) && (localcursor.getCount() > 0)) {
        arrayOfString = new ArrayList < String > ();
        localcursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            arrayOfString.add(localcursor.getString(localcursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.CITY_NAME)) + "-" + localcursor.getString(localcursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.CITY_COUNTRY)));
        } while (localcursor.moveToNext());

        this.multiSelectCities.setThreshold(3);
        adapter = new CityDataWithMultitextAdapter(this, arrayOfString);
        multiSelectCities.setAdapter(adapter);
        multiSelectCities.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());

        /* localcursor.close(); */

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { //SEARCH BUTTON CLICK AND STORE THE DATA INTO LISTVIEW

        if (!Utils.isEmpty(multiSelectCities)) {
            arrayList = multiSelectCities.getText().toString().substring(0, multiSelectCities.length() - 1).split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
                selectedItems.add(arrayList[i].trim());
            }
        } else {
            Utils.displayToast(this, "Please Enter City/Cities");
        }

        CityListAdapter adapter = new CityListAdapter(this, selectedItems);
        listCity.setAdapter(adapter);
        multiSelectCities.setText("");
        listCity.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(CityListDataActivity.this, CityListDetail.class);
                i.putExtra("CITY_NAME", selectedItems.get(position).toString());
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

I am thinking to check entered values with Database by **SELECT** Query but i have 75000+ records so its difficult solution for this.

[image]

Any Help? It will be Appreciated.

Comment: what does *rather than ADAPTER values* mean ?

Comment: means here this time you can add any string by clicking on button it will add in `listview`

Comment: is that some sort of search history ? can't you just add it to the list if the user selected an item from the AutoCompleteTextView?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to remove the possibility to write inside the AutoCompleteTextView with:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
            android:editable="false"
            android:inputType="none"
    ..../>
```

And onTouch call show adapter, that will show the list of cities.

```
 private AutoCompleteTextView mAutoText;

 mAutoText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mAutoText.showDropDown();
                mAutoText.setListSelection(mPos);
                return false;
            }


        });
mAutoText.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            mAdapter.setSelection(position);
            mPos = position;

        }
    });
```

Comment: mAdapter.setSelection(position); not recognized method

Comment: @NinjaCoding https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection(int)